# What is the Angular JS Equivalent of $.ajaxPreFilter()

Tags: angularjs

I have a JQuery $.ajaxPreFilter function I need to use in my angular app:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    if (options.data) {
        options.data += '&sessionId=' + sessionId;
    } else {
        options.data = 'sessionId=' + sessionId;
    }
});
```

What would an angular 1.x equivalent of this function look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$http interceptors. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http and look at interceptors. The docs are pretty sparse. These articles: https://thinkster.io/interceptors, http://onehungrymind.com/winning-http-interceptors-angularjs/ and http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/ are all pretty good references.